# VS2015: Recover code from file in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

First of all I am not using any kind of subversion file, any Git, any TFS.

Once tell that I would like to recover a function I moved yesterday to other file and it accidentally deleted.

Is it possible to recover that function?

It is javascript file

Comment: Visual studio doesn't make back up copies, but there are programs which can recover deleted files from your hard-drive, so long as the file itself hasn't been physically overwritten.

Comment: Another option to prevent this in future is to install a clipboard manager, which automatically keeps copies of anything you copy and paste. If you'd had a clipboard manager installed, it would have kept a copy of the function when you copied and pasted the function to the new file.  I use Ditto, which is open source, but there are many options.  Ditto has saved my skin quite a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a backup of the file (eg. in recycle bin) then: No.

Learn a lesson: version control is very important, use it even on your smallest personal projects.

Comment: I know and I use but well I said a small lie ... :P I am using subversion but Files are unprotected and new.

Comment: In eclipse that possibility exists vs2015 should implement just I asked if vs2015 had that.... No copy in recycle :(. thx

Comment: @David: small frequent checkins is part of using a VCS well.